# Visual Studio. Same path for different computers/users

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I started a project on my house computer and set the includes and libs paths: "C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\project1\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)"
"C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\project1\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)".

My problem is when i'm in a different computer or user, when i open the project, the paths are the same but those path doesn't exist because the user is different and i'm changing the paths everytime i change computers/users.

How can i set that the paths starts at "Documents\GitHub\project1..." so it works for all computers/users?

I'm using visual studio 2015.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use macros like $(SolutionDir) or $(ProjectDir) to make the path relative to the project.

You can find them in the edit panel for paths, there's a button named Macros..

[image]

[image]